# Hide selected option from first dropdown on the next dropdown

Tags: html, angularjs, select, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a dynamic form that has dropdown select. I get the data from the option using ng repeat and then display it onthe dropdown. My code somewhat goes like this.

```
<select name="languageCat" id="languageCat" ng-model="languageItem.languageCat" ng-required="true" required>
     <option value="">---Please select---</option>
     <option ng-repeat="item in scpLangCat" value="{{item.language_name}}">{{item.language_name}} - {{item.language_description}}</option>
 </select>
```

I get the data from this API call.

```
Service.fetchDropdownData('language')
 .then(function(data){
     $scope.scpLangCat = data.data;
     localStorage.LanguageCategory = JSON.stringify(data.data);
 })
```

This dropdown is in my dynamic form. I I selected a value in the first form in this dropdown, I need to hide that value on the second dropdown in the second form. The addition of dynamic form code is this.

```
scope.addLanguageItem = function() {
            $scope.LanguageFormData.language.push({ bName: null, pName: null, pNameSub: null, lFeature: null, lIngredient: null, lInstruction: null, languageCat: null });
            $scope.disablebrand=false;

    };
```

How can I possibly do that?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by model-binding and ng-hide if the option is equal to some value (from the first dropdown). Assuming you are binding to "data" in the first dropdown, have you tried something along the lines of (in the second dropdown):

```
<option ng-repeat="item in scpLangCat" ng-hide="data.someValue == item.someValue" value="{{item.language_name}}">{{item.language_name}} - {{item.language_description}}</option>
```

Comment: I didn't get it. Where will i get the data.someValue?

Comment: Do you have the same list of values that bind to both dropdowns?

Comment: Yes, I get the values from database that has language_id, language_name, and language_description

Comment: I saw the fiddle but your using two selects, I am using one form only with one select dropdown. I am just using ng-reat to add forms dynamically in angularway

Answer (score 0):

If you have forms created like this

```
<div ng-repeat="(index,scpLangCat) in LanguageFormData">
    <select name="languageCat[index]" id="{{'languageCat_' + index}}" ng-model="languageItem.languageCat[index]" ng-required="true" required
    ng-options="item.language_name +' - ' + item.language_description as item.label for item in getCategories() track by item.language_name">
    </select>
</div>
```

You can implement getCategories this way:

```
$scope.getCategories() = function() {
    return $scope.scpLangCat.filter(function(item){return $scope.languageItem.languageCat.indexOf(item.language_name)==-1);
}
```

Comment: I am using one form only. I used ng-repeat to dynamically add forms